# How many times has Mjolnir been broken?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir

When looking for an answer to a different question, I came across this comic panel, showing the Hulk grabbing and shattering Thor's hammer:

[image]

How many times has Thor's hammer been destroyed?

Comment: [Six times Mjolnir has been broken](http://legionofleia.com/2017/04/thor-hammer-mjolnir/)

Comment: Can you link the answer of where that comic panel came from? It might affect my answer.

Comment: @Skooba - I think it was an answer on here, actually but I can't find it. I'm looking.

Comment: @Skooba - That's from *INCREDIBLE HULK* 227 - and, it's a dream that Banner/Hulk is having, monitored by Doc Samson (He's the one saying "I ... can't believe this.")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mjolnir](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir) has been destroyed a total of six times in the comics.

The panel you have listed comes from Incredible Hulk #227 and is a dream sequence and so is not counted as an actual breaking event. (Thanks to @RDFozz in the [comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174163/how-many-times-has-mjolnir-been-broken/174171?noredirect=1#comment468359_174163))

> Although an incredibly powerful weapon, Mjolnir is not indestructible. It has been damaged several times over the years:
>
> - A force beam from the Destroyer slices it in two in Journey Into
>   Mystery #119. Mjolnir was repaired in Journey Into Mystery #120.
> - The Molecule Man dispels the atomic bonds between the hammer's
>   molecules, vaporizing Mjolnir in Avengers #215. Mjolnir was restored
>   in Avengers #216.
> - The hammer shatters after channeling an incredible amount of energy
>   at the Celestial Exitar in Thor #388 and was restored by the
>   Celestials' replicoid in Thor #389
> - Dark God Perrikus slices Mjolnir in half with a magical scythe in
>   Thor Vol 2 #10. Mjolnir was restored in Thor Vol 2 #11
> - The hammer is shattered when it collides with the uru weapons of
>   Loki's followers, resulting in an atomic-scale explosion in Thor Vol
>   2 #80. Mjolnir wasn't seen again until Thor Vol 3 #1.
> - The hammer was shattered by Bor in Thor #600, requiring Doctor
>   Strange to reconstruct it by channeling Thor's Odinforce into its
>   fragments.

<sub>Thanks to @Valorum's [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174163/how-many-times-has-mjolnir-been-broken#comment468285_174163) which led me to a *different* source for the information</sub>

Comment: What, no pictures?

Comment: As noted in the main comments, the panel shown is from a dream - doesn't really count.

Comment: Mb skoobs, I completely misread your little subscript statement.