# Can Hulk become strong enough to break Uru and similar metals?

Tags: marvel, comics, the-incredible-hulk

As Marvel creators (namely Stan Lee) have hinted at many times (and Hulk has reiterated throughout the comic books), Hulk is the strongest there is. This is because if the opponent is stronger, Hulk gets mad and gets even stronger with time, to the point where he surpasses his opponent's strength.

Does that mean that given enough time, the big Green Dunderhead can break Uru or other similar metals?

Comment: Related - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174163/how-many-times-has-mjolnir-been-broken

Comment: This is, to a large extent, an opinion-based question in my view; a question that's been debated on comicbook forums for decades without resolution. In my opinion, yes, the Hulk likely can get strong enough in theory to break metals like enchanted uru or True Adamantium. There's no absolute proof of that though, just statements that his strength can increase without limit, and showings where he did get a lot stronger, without it being clear whether he was strong enough to break enchanted uru.

Comment: I guess this boils down to how angry can the Hulk get with metal?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, did you mean how angry Hulk can get with the situation?

Comment: @justanotherguy or the metal itself. I mean this is magic metal, maybe it could start talking to Hulk empathetically and de-escalate the situation as a defensive mechanism.